# Magento categories as grid , which massactions would you find usefull?

Tags: magento

I`m about to create an extension that will list categories in backend as grid. Which massactions and functionality would you use. Something like deactivate all products in a category etc.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You will get a better response if you show what you have already tried or investigated.

Comment: I`ve got grid with configurable columns. So that you can select which attributes to show. A demo i`ll setup tomorrow

Comment: You will have troubles creating a backend grid with categories. Mainly because the category model has this method `getChildren` and in the grid html there is this `if ($_multipleRows = $this->getMultipleRows($_item)):...`  and `getMultipleRows` is a wrapper for `$_item->getChildren()`. The expected behavior of this method is not what the method from the category model does. I know this is not related to the question but I thought you might want a 'heads-up'. Nobody told me that and I hit a brick wall fast when trying to do this.

Comment: I`m not sure that i`m to implement the logic of standard magento categories tree  . I think there will be a filter for parent and child categories

Comment: I didn't have enough time to setup a demo site so i did it first today. You can take a look at the extension under 17.the-web-service.de/admin User:categorygrid Pwd:categorygrid12345